# Disable mails notifications on items/folders ALFRESCO 5.2

Tags: javascript, node.js, alfresco, aspect

I created this JS code to disable and enable notifications on a click on a button:

(Action.min.js):

```
var me = this,
        jsNode = record.jsNode,
        content = jsNode.isContainer ? "folder" : "document";

     if (jsNode.hasAspect("cm:emailed"))
     {
         // add code to disable notifications
         Alfresco.util.PopupManager.displayMessage(
                       {
                          text: this.msg("message.notification.disable")
                       });
     }

     else {
         // add code to enable notifications
         Alfresco.util.PopupManager.displayMessage(
                       {
                          text: this.msg("message.notification.enable")
                       });
     }
```

},

The trick Im trying to do is disable send mail rule on certain folder. I wonder if that is possible.

I use alfresco 5.2
thank you

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do something like that. You could turn off notifications for the whole site though, and then use rules on specific folders (where you want to send notifications) to "turn them back up" (in reality, to send them).

Comment: I know it's not the normal behavior of ALFRESCO, but It's what the client wants ...